# Scraping google search results and getting the category which google uses to define it

Tags: web-scraping, google-search-api, google-business

I'm working on a project which requires the category which google uses to define that business/store. I'm using beautiful soup library but I am unable to extract that specific part of the result. I'll show you with a help of an example using the image below:
[click to open the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZpb9.png)

when I search "bell canada" for example, I get search results and also you can see a box which google shows on the right side of the page which summaries the search "bell canada".
So my task required, extracting the subtitle under BELL CANADA named as **Telecommunications company** .
How can I achieve this for any search on google using web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you're using the [latest version of `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent) e.g Chrome version.
- The result will be parsed only if the search result would have a Knowledge graph displayed.
- If you need to extract just one element, you can use `select_one()` method from `beautifulsoup` which uses `CSS` selectors to find an element. Sometimes it's better than `find()` (check out [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) to grab CSS selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser)

---

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/scraping-google-search-results-and-getting-the-category-whic#main.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": "bell canada",  # search query
    "gl": "us",          # country to search from   
    "hl": "en"           # language
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

subtitle = soup.select_one(".wwUB2c span").text
print(subtitle)
```

Output:

```
Telecommunications company
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi, it's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference is that you don't need to create a parser from scratch, maintain it, or figure out how to bypass blocks from Google or other search engines.

Example code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os 

params = {
  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # your serpapi API key
  "engine": "google",               # search engine
  "q": "bell canada",               # search query
  "gl": "us",                       # country to search from
  "hl": "en"                        # language
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

result = results["knowledge_graph"].get("type")
print(result)

# Telecommunications company
```

Full JSON Knowledge Graph output:

```json
{
  "title": "Bell Canada",
  "type": "Telecommunications company",
  "place_id": "ChIJQaXUmDm7j4ARY4k9pa41rcs",
  "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20b07f241e63c1a8af.png",
  "website": "http://www.bell.ca/",
  "description": "Bell Canada is a Canadian telecommunications company headquartered at 1 Carrefour Alexander-Graham-Bell in the borough of Verdun in Montreal, Quebec, Canada. It is an ILEC in the provinces of Ontario and Quebec; as such, it was a founding member of the Stentor Alliance.",
  "source": {
    "name": "Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_Canada"
  },
  "headquarters": "Montreal, Canada",
  "headquarters_links": [
    {
      "text": "Headquarters",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+headquarters&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vS0spOttLPL0pPzMusSizJzM9D4VhlpCamFJYmFpWkFhUvYpVISs3JUUhOzEtMSVRAlgIAJLjc3VQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFUQAg"
    },
    {
      "text": "Montreal, Canada",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Montreal&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tS4gAxTY0KzLW0spOt9POL0hPzMqsSSzLz81A4VhmpiSmFpYlFJalFxYtYOXzz80qKUhNzdrAy7mJn4mAAAKldbGxWAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAXoECFUQAw"
    }
  ],
  "ceo": "Mirko Bibic (Jan 2020\u2013)",
  "ceo_links": [
    {
      "text": "CEO",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+ceo&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vSUsxOttLPL0pPzMusSizJzM9D4Vglp-YvYuVPSs3JUUhOzEtMSVQAigAAyDZ50kIAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFoQAg"
    },
    {
      "text": "Mirko Bibic",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Mirko+Bibic&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tS4tFP1zc0MjWpMKyoSNFSzE620s8vSk_My6xKLMnMz0PhWCWn5i9i5fbNLMrOV3DKTMpM3sHKuIudiYMBAJXG1PxUAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAXoECFoQAw"
    }
  ],
  "revenue": "23.96 billion CAD (2019)",
  "revenue_links": [
    {
      "text": "Revenue",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+revenue&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vSUskot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrYpSy1LzSlMXsQonpebkKCQn5iWmJCpARQEd2EpcSQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFgQAg"
    }
  ],
  "founded": "April 29, 1880",
  "founded_links": [
    {
      "text": "Founded",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+founded&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vSUs1OttLPL0pPzMusSizJzM9D4Vil5ZfmpaSmLGIVTkrNyVFITsxLTElUgIoCAKNSAMBKAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFcQAg"
    }
  ],
  "subsidiaries": "Bell Mobility, Bell Fibe TV, Bell Media, Bell Aliant, MORE",
  "subsidiaries_links": [
    {
      "text": "Subsidiaries",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+subsidiaries&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vS0swot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrYpLk4ozUzITizJTixexSiSl5uQoJCfmJaYkKiBLAQC0i8LLUwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFYQAg"
    },
    {
      "text": "Bell Mobility",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Mobility&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tSAjONLCotk7Q0M8qt9JPzc3JSk0sy8_P084vSE_MyqxJBnGKr4tKk4syUzMSizNTiRay8Tqk5OQq--UmZOZkllTtYGXexM3EwAgDhYoVcWwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAXoECFYQAw"
    },
    {
      "text": "Bell Fibe TV",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Fibe+TV&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tS4gIxk_MqzIvStDQzyq30k_NzclKTSzLz8_Tzi9IT8zKrEkGcYqvi0qTizJTMxKLM1OJFrDxOqTk5Cm6ZSakKIWE7WBl3sTNxMAIAwCwzNFsAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAnoECFYQBA"
    },
    {
      "text": "Bell Media",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Media&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tSAjONLCotC7Q0M8qt9JPzc3JSk0sy8_P084vSE_MyqxJBnGKr4tKk4syUzMSizNTiRaxcTqk5OQq-qUCBHayMu9iZOBgBIdpKolgAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoA3oECFYQBQ"
    },
    {
      "text": "Bell Aliant",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Aliant&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tSAjONs6qKMrQ0M8qt9JPzc3JSk0sy8_P084vSE_MyqxJBnGKr4tKk4syUzMSizNTiRazcTqk5OQqOOZmJeSU7WBl3sTNxMAIAPghHPVkAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoBHoECFYQBg"
    },
    {
      "text": "MORE",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+subsidiaries&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vS0swot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrYpLk4ozUzITizJTixexSiSl5uQoJCfmJaYkKiBLAQC0i8LLUwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ44YBKAV6BAhWEAc"
    }
  ],
  "parent_organization": "BCE Inc.",
  "parent_organization_links": [
    {
      "text": "Parent organization",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+parent+organization&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vSMsgot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrQoSi1LzShSQBRexyiel5uQoJCfmJaYkKmBRAQDkOSRXYQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFIQAg"
    },
    {
      "text": "BCE Inc.",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=BCE+Inc.&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tS4tVP1zc0TM6pSs8ryCnSMsgot9JPzs_JSU0uyczP088vSk_My6xKBHGKrQoSi1LzShSQBRexcjg5uyp45iXr7WBl3MXOxMEAAJpETrZhAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAXoECFIQAw"
    }
  ],
  "founders": "Alexander Graham Bell, Charles Fleetford Sise",
  "founders_links": [
    {
      "text": "Founders",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=bell+canada+founders&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0vSUs9OttJPKi3OzEstLoYz4vMLUosSSzLz86zS8kvzUlKLFrGKJKXm5CgkJ-YlpiQqQEWLAVSO90hNAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQ6BMoAHoECFMQAg"
    },
    {
      "text": "Alexander Graham Bell",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Alexander+Graham+Bell&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tSYgcxs80NtNSzk630k0qLM_NSi4vhjPj8gtSixJLM_DyrtPzSvJTUokWsoo45qRWJILaCe1FiRmKuglNqTs4OVsZd7EwcjADv87IIXwAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAXoECFMQAw"
    },
    {
      "text": "Charles Fleetford Sise",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Charles+Fleetford+Sise&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MMxJz0tS4gIxjcqrzKoqtdSzk630k0qLM_NSi4vhjPj8gtSixJLM_DyrtPzSvJTUokWsYs4ZiUU5qcUKbjmpqSVp-UUpCsGZxak7WBl3sTNxMAIAu9x5NWMAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQmxMoAnoECFMQBA"
    }
  ],
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Facebook",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/BellCanada",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=bell+canada",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc2074c7067793bbe8078324a0faa409aa72ae97cc00dde05d3d.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "LinkedIn",
      "link": "https://www.linkedin.com/company/bell",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=bell+canada",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc2074c7067793bbe8077149819227ec3fe420490a616cb7a98b.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Instagram",
      "link": "https://www.instagram.com/bell",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=bell+canada",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc2074c7067793bbe80701ded0bf9c7339eb0750d18f70d41a8e.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Twitter",
      "link": "https://twitter.com/Bell_News",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=bell+canada",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc2074c7067793bbe807ac0352770d2c1364de5875551883bbf0.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "YouTube",
      "link": "https://www.youtube.com/user/bellcanada",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=bell+canada",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc2074c7067793bbe807aca6f6c897bc56669105a3fa347dd780.png"
    }
  ],
  "people_also_search_for": [
    {
      "name": "Bell Mobility",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Mobility&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1R9UAvwmMtikZ7R6go3IFYLEBqyQrZaG4BLS5p3WFt0rrwQLldwNDkd8S1-6xh6XzROLNmWPjEn63m_JtfsUpeGnJ1sZ5ZrfygGyNjqzZYRQUeiBl6zZ3AHaXiz88P22q3s_YpZGtyao5_7p1pRjhBRMQyhXg-PRV6Xf5Cqukh3H14ooklpf80wV_TODtWV1EKdhiC82QvehgQ6nBqVdkEN0OY9i136n3i8xQnKQVXOmGQKlgnE7ZoUYz6VvineQnxQhTjk%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQxA16BAhUEAU",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=Bell+Mobility&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1R9UAvwmMtikZ7R6go3IFYLEBqyQrZaG4BLS5p3WFt0rrwQLldwNDkd8S1-6xh6XzROLNmWPjEn63m_JtfsUpeGnJ1sZ5ZrfygGyNjqzZYRQUeiBl6zZ3AHaXiz88P22q3s_YpZGtyao5_7p1pRjhBRMQyhXg-PRV6Xf5Cqukh3H14ooklpf80wV_TODtWV1EKdhiC82QvehgQ6nBqVdkEN0OY9i136n3i8xQnKQVXOmGQKlgnE7ZoUYz6VvineQnxQhTjk%3D",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20c56ba723d853f90fc6315fa2689fcfb45a4b2a45d9fae90403c0d82e4a40d42b.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rogers Communications",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Rogers+Communications&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1dzM_m9DQbE44YUabMcVuyLEzIAhZ3H2Ffy87BzHf7w7Eyu5_QEgCc-vJB0RWaeMzFlsDk1chAWxn8TCFqAnREbojgzTt19P5wVcvFN-qGPr88al2xsnGebQ167KSGOKLrBJhLPuvhjMdtl5xGEenGV8M6hmipQ-UhzJhuTftp1PKWGWSR9ZleVlYAaFN-oPOINFXJ9mt4tOhnfVLP-auA9-ZdIA6-h22xSlZWQqm7W9w12ezMpjfZuQqJO0hOXwoIk__ZO-iER0syJJSIceMmG9NPg2&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQxA16BAhUEAc",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=Rogers+Communications&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1dzM_m9DQbE44YUabMcVuyLEzIAhZ3H2Ffy87BzHf7w7Eyu5_QEgCc-vJB0RWaeMzFlsDk1chAWxn8TCFqAnREbojgzTt19P5wVcvFN-qGPr88al2xsnGebQ167KSGOKLrBJhLPuvhjMdtl5xGEenGV8M6hmipQ-UhzJhuTftp1PKWGWSR9ZleVlYAaFN-oPOINFXJ9mt4tOhnfVLP-auA9-ZdIA6-h22xSlZWQqm7W9w12ezMpjfZuQqJO0hOXwoIk__ZO-iER0syJJSIceMmG9NPg2",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20c56ba723d853f90fc6315fa2689fcfb4c7166733dc5a6aba38cf161f2a757494.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Telus",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Telus&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1avwx721CKW5xFPqY8J24d9HoDRlbSmY_hJ3bLjDSyrYAhUDJ7NPnSUsZP-EodZiQ7lcNnn6zw6GmEG97o7wfrx9GGsw36qfjTUEeKsmbjB1Eu6-3VdGNvabNha80f9AJyZugh2oTfK3Je7UW6NJKddrU1s_rpzpuMpaIaq_XEgweuW_Oh-qyor8ealTV2tasEWtmrNH9ELh8Qr0WjipAWgyWPAOy33BAPYdul4_tNs2tgPq8rQr0SS6yFXbTgS2YySzrH0%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQxA16BAhUEAk",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=Telus&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1avwx721CKW5xFPqY8J24d9HoDRlbSmY_hJ3bLjDSyrYAhUDJ7NPnSUsZP-EodZiQ7lcNnn6zw6GmEG97o7wfrx9GGsw36qfjTUEeKsmbjB1Eu6-3VdGNvabNha80f9AJyZugh2oTfK3Je7UW6NJKddrU1s_rpzpuMpaIaq_XEgweuW_Oh-qyor8ealTV2tasEWtmrNH9ELh8Qr0WjipAWgyWPAOy33BAPYdul4_tNs2tgPq8rQr0SS6yFXbTgS2YySzrH0%3D",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20c56ba723d853f90fc6315fa2689fcfb4ef927ce4febcc787bb372f154e1ab257.png"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bell Satellite TV",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Satellite+TV&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1R_XB3ccGKnGM0ZWrwNs4AfVgIEjRog7cnGYpULPf3NHggGWhZu06mYq6FwuKWiqDluDkFpFfHCqo6EZT-fSbk237oI3ER1G7BPe5c23kxRoP2DjMeuiCj36HGT0G1mHYk4oqhO2mfL5vBe9SNAG9vkMwDPBevv39jCosyf4unz8msh_oPcxbmt9guiYsqPDsuWMW5qbjJk9VnI178i8sIRuww27hhsmsfX7tjqEyIb1yHfG0Jc-1fxB50qXmo8kZ1rhmjQ%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQxA16BAhUEAs",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=Bell+Satellite+TV&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1R_XB3ccGKnGM0ZWrwNs4AfVgIEjRog7cnGYpULPf3NHggGWhZu06mYq6FwuKWiqDluDkFpFfHCqo6EZT-fSbk237oI3ER1G7BPe5c23kxRoP2DjMeuiCj36HGT0G1mHYk4oqhO2mfL5vBe9SNAG9vkMwDPBevv39jCosyf4unz8msh_oPcxbmt9guiYsqPDsuWMW5qbjJk9VnI178i8sIRuww27hhsmsfX7tjqEyIb1yHfG0Jc-1fxB50qXmo8kZ1rhmjQ%3D",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20c56ba723d853f90fc6315fa2689fcfb438c5d18c0d72fc2c338cfdf89f7d79ed.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bell Internet",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Internet&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1fuHSkPMK_DYNjyh5MCv1jI4fqIb0Y65kvtJEsFZiVMzyVFwIrZzQDRGHfsOb2zza3VseJPDDPsHk8DFp-GpKcL81MCRae8eeO5kgTN-q6oCXW-8ae-Vk7qtQGOkJ2RrivNU8rh_LlzRAmI57laCuyA5Q7twiXJPUIWn9od4hQKfSJSzQBHc6IeuuNIjv9VHiRJVuoHIVBRTTpdRWXy-_3LUfIfr1DtDobSoycKlY6qR9txE6iT53DlIcIKRLzDAzE5Ra7M%3D&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQxA16BAhUEA0",
      "serpapi_link": "https://serpapi.com/search.json?device=desktop&engine=google&gl=us&google_domain=google.com&hl=en&q=Bell+Internet&si=ANhW_NqMq05hm_NHatki2oB83qRn9HU6YTauVAJv82wgMbWR1fuHSkPMK_DYNjyh5MCv1jI4fqIb0Y65kvtJEsFZiVMzyVFwIrZzQDRGHfsOb2zza3VseJPDDPsHk8DFp-GpKcL81MCRae8eeO5kgTN-q6oCXW-8ae-Vk7qtQGOkJ2RrivNU8rh_LlzRAmI57laCuyA5Q7twiXJPUIWn9od4hQKfSJSzQBHc6IeuuNIjv9VHiRJVuoHIVBRTTpdRWXy-_3LUfIfr1DtDobSoycKlY6qR9txE6iT53DlIcIKRLzDAzE5Ra7M%3D",
      "image": "https://serpapi.com/searches/624d3ef03d69195733337a68/images/f8d5105f4a126e851d64734cda40fc20c56ba723d853f90fc6315fa2689fcfb4291421c753a92f6fe72135100c226cb4.jpeg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pacific Bell",
      "extensions": [
        "Telephone company"
      ],
      "place_id": "7872218611778819527",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&q=Bell+Telephone+Canada&rflfq=1&num=20&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAACVQu20cMRDFBRYU30oKGG0J8_-kdgMO3MBCWkHB4k7QdeQKXJeq0KM8AEnwceZ9eH83lqwU4QrmzCpulxwPrOLeydlFpD1LgFKqm6szmZZTVRpQcYtMwJpirC4SY2lyYhJGq3t6mPJYhCyMoVhGraVAxxKchvL5ZqnqMaW4wWBW3WyCpTbn2ZOsKFRNfI5jPtt7moLsNylMjDPcoZc54Ngjy2EpBCEhA8JABCWbSYlZBGmSq029kGIs2sTW2AuGJPN_q7kBLzXCSa7FBdQp8TtUDlpRK_gZi4PNlXleiVKiaCwQsuxJw94s7SzojO7yCpKWZFV8-DhLSTbG05E8rIP-nU6fp6ff-_X92NftuF3X2759PL-tr9ePvz8ef-7Hsf7Zj_397XrZ11_bZXvZvgBP7Lvh3wEAAA",
      "image": "/maps/vt/data=35Ij67gvdt8gd0NJKUYCZj3ZRJBpEjaJcHDm9Xl3KmNVaH1OJ9CYXbiidynalny2EBchT2rufd2QVU5FUbQfp7nchYu5KUA0_J3a1yYy46SsXK4KkeeXh3rkQndrBx8aAtQLmzqFonP-PQ7C"
    },
    {
      "name": "PLALCA12 Central Office",
      "extensions": [
        "Telephone company"
      ],
      "place_id": "13255971798003999992",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&q=Bell+Telephone+Canada&rflfq=1&num=20&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAACVQu20cMRDFBRYU30oKGG0J8_-kdgMO3MBCWkHB4k7QdeQKXJeq0KM8AEnwceZ9eH83lqwU4QrmzCpulxwPrOLeydlFpD1LgFKqm6szmZZTVRpQcYtMwJpirC4SY2lyYhJGq3t6mPJYhCyMoVhGraVAxxKchvL5ZqnqMaW4wWBW3WyCpTbn2ZOsKFRNfI5jPtt7moLsNylMjDPcoZc54Ngjy2EpBCEhA8JABCWbSYlZBGmSq029kGIs2sTW2AuGJPN_q7kBLzXCSa7FBdQp8TtUDlpRK_gZi4PNlXleiVKiaCwQsuxJw94s7SzojO7yCpKWZFV8-DhLSTbG05E8rIP-nU6fp6ff-_X92NftuF3X2759PL-tr9ePvz8ef-7Hsf7Zj_397XrZ11_bZXvZvgBP7Lvh3wEAAA",
      "image": "/maps/vt/data=4rthHhRCfZXURzK-kzMzSCtsBPnG4xHtl1JuySthFDTg7w9NM3hPnGZjVRIpR49EMbd6kP1Y1ZDxIjaDdX7v_JGvZLrbdqj5EO5C_wNEL8r8RPtIg_jkAdnhgPvskot35L6unuxB9PJ5phjk"
    },
    {
      "name": "AT&T Internet Service",
      "extensions": [
        "Internet service provider"
      ],
      "place_id": "10735453510438508874",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&q=Bell+Telephone+Canada&rflfq=1&num=20&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAACVQu20cMRDFBRYU30oKGG0J8_-kdgMO3MBCWkHB4k7QdeQKXJeq0KM8AEnwceZ9eH83lqwU4QrmzCpulxwPrOLeydlFpD1LgFKqm6szmZZTVRpQcYtMwJpirC4SY2lyYhJGq3t6mPJYhCyMoVhGraVAxxKchvL5ZqnqMaW4wWBW3WyCpTbn2ZOsKFRNfI5jPtt7moLsNylMjDPcoZc54Ngjy2EpBCEhA8JABCWbSYlZBGmSq029kGIs2sTW2AuGJPN_q7kBLzXCSa7FBdQp8TtUDlpRK_gZi4PNlXleiVKiaCwQsuxJw94s7SzojO7yCpKWZFV8-DhLSTbG05E8rIP-nU6fp6ff-_X92NftuF3X2759PL-tr9ePvz8ef-7Hsf7Zj_397XrZ11_bZXvZvgBP7Lvh3wEAAA",
      "image": "/maps/vt/data=TMQY8k8OAt51uboJ-OAxE8rQDF7N3xtmkvaaWOdr_uxxnKj5-fs1bPNRvrzDR9NcNNrGvRrcXGbPORZLxV7yrah4W714KMFrSTnPP6E7oU2wO4vFbPBGB2BsvdRTdE0ryTBpjJ35nrCTCL2l"
    },
    {
      "name": "Professional Communications Services/ProComm",
      "extensions": [
        "Telephone answering service"
      ],
      "place_id": "12546775353724135226",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&q=Bell+Telephone+Canada&rflfq=1&num=20&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAACVQu20cMRDFBRYU30oKGG0J8_-kdgMO3MBCWkHB4k7QdeQKXJeq0KM8AEnwceZ9eH83lqwU4QrmzCpulxwPrOLeydlFpD1LgFKqm6szmZZTVRpQcYtMwJpirC4SY2lyYhJGq3t6mPJYhCyMoVhGraVAxxKchvL5ZqnqMaW4wWBW3WyCpTbn2ZOsKFRNfI5jPtt7moLsNylMjDPcoZc54Ngjy2EpBCEhA8JABCWbSYlZBGmSq029kGIs2sTW2AuGJPN_q7kBLzXCSa7FBdQp8TtUDlpRK_gZi4PNlXleiVKiaCwQsuxJw94s7SzojO7yCpKWZFV8-DhLSTbG05E8rIP-nU6fp6ff-_X92NftuF3X2759PL-tr9ePvz8ef-7Hsf7Zj_397XrZ11_bZXvZvgBP7Lvh3wEAAA",
      "image": "/maps/vt/data=9dPkYHZyTO-CbttEkSVhUJCe91_uc1MydmP8hF5owQhQ7HFwUsUnVO9EIfSzg7FfYoOHaiMETvxEKpHpxsIXNZFTn687rsldtI7GPQEpwwr2SjmKYq25SJpl7otLS6kg031psXCO6xYKhLbW"
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiber Internet Center",
      "extensions": [
        "Internet service provider"
      ],
      "place_id": "9050102110455756431",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?tbm=lcl&q=Bell+Telephone+Canada&rflfq=1&num=20&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAACVQu20cMRDFBRYU30oKGG0J8_-kdgMO3MBCWkHB4k7QdeQKXJeq0KM8AEnwceZ9eH83lqwU4QrmzCpulxwPrOLeydlFpD1LgFKqm6szmZZTVRpQcYtMwJpirC4SY2lyYhJGq3t6mPJYhCyMoVhGraVAxxKchvL5ZqnqMaW4wWBW3WyCpTbn2ZOsKFRNfI5jPtt7moLsNylMjDPcoZc54Ngjy2EpBCEhA8JABCWbSYlZBGmSq029kGIs2sTW2AuGJPN_q7kBLzXCSa7FBdQp8TtUDlpRK_gZi4PNlXleiVKiaCwQsuxJw94s7SzojO7yCpKWZFV8-DhLSTbG05E8rIP-nU6fp6ff-_X92NftuF3X2759PL-tr9ePvz8ef-7Hsf7Zj_397XrZ11_bZXvZvgBP7Lvh3wEAAA",
      "image": "/maps/vt/data=BKw9RQ3VtjggI2Pv_zM9xpB8ENL2dEdyZZwgge81TdfAzzgwfw2vF9u1NvnGmqxYdw-oMs0qhdvirPaIFNOLT1tcXe5bvi9pf-f484dREAef1M3xiH5N27GhnBDLov7joDapvJsk_yNeaMWk"
    }
  ],
  "people_also_search_for_link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Bell+Canada&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MMxJz0tSQjC1BIMzU1LLEyuL_VIrSoJLUguKF7FyO6Xm5Cg4J-YlpiTuYGUEAMq8ASI8AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRtYnu8v72AhVAg3IEHeNNAtwQMSgAegQIVBAB",
  "people_also_search_for_stick": "H4sIAAAAAAAAAONgFuLUz9U3MMxJz0tSQjC1BIMzU1LLEyuL_VIrSoJLUguKF7FyO6Xm5Cg4J-YlpiTuYGUEAMq8ASI8AAAA"
}
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Comment: I get None value for subtitle = soup.select_one('.wwUB2c span').text

Comment: @foxel If you copied the script above without updating `user-agent`, that is possibly what causes the problem. I [updated the code in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/scraping-google-search-results-and-getting-the-category-whic#main.py), double-checked and it's working with the same selector as written in the answer. [Check what's your current `user-agent`](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/).